# Are nodejs filesystem error codes reliable cross-platform?

Tags: node.js, filesystems

If I run the following:

```
require('fs').readFile('C:/music/sound.wav')
  .then(buff => console.log(`Got ${buff.length} bytes of music`))
  .catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err.code}`));
```

And I am on windows, with `C:/music/sound.wav` **missing**, I will hit the error handler, and learn that `err.code` is equal to `'ENOENT'` ([which means "error no entry" / "file not found"](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/operating-system-error-codes/)).

Can I perform error handling using `err.code` in a cross-platform-reliable way? Will linux and other operating systems also indicate "file not found" with that exact same string? In general, are `err.code` values consistent across OSes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In general, are err.code values consistent across OSes?

Yes.

If you look at one of the implementation files for the `fs` module such as [rimraf.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/fs/rimraf.js#L33) which is very much cross platform code, you will see all sorts of logic references to code such as 'ENOTEMPTY', 'EEXIST', 'EPERM', 'EBUSY', 'EMFILE', 'ENFILE', 'ENOENT', 'EISDIR', etc... which indicates that the nodejs cross platform fs code itself is using the error codes in a way that assumes they are cross platform.

That particular rimraf.js file has 5 separate comparisons for ENOENT indicating that it is certainly using that error code in a cross platform way.